# Combine Results from Two PDO queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following line:

```
$products = $dbh->query("SELECT piP2Components.typeID, invTypes.typeName FROM piP2Components INNER JOIN invTypes ON piP2Components.typeID = invTypes.typeID ORDER BY invTypes.typeName ASC;");
```

I have another table, piP3Components and I would like to run the same query on it and have the results added to the $products variable. As the result is a PDOStatement object I can't simply array_push.

How would I go about doing this? Alternatively, I'm fairly new to using JOIN queries, is there a way to accomplish this in SQL without having the piP3Components.typeID results in a different column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options.

First, if the columns you're picking from each table have identical column types, you can [use a `UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM something WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT qux AS foo, meta AS bar, syntactic AS baz FROM elsewhere WHERE ...
```

Second, you can run both queries, then fetch the results for each and place them in a single array, using that array later instead of the statement handle when processing the results:

```
$results = array();

$sth_a = $pdo->prepare(...);
$sth_a->execute(...);
while($row = $sth_a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $results[] = $row;

$sth_b = $pdo->prepare(...);
$sth_b->execute(...);
while($row = $sth_b->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $results[] = $row;

print_r($results);
```