# How to Merge PDO Mysql Array Data using Php

Tags: php, pdo

I need to merge categories and subcategories into one array. Here is code.

```
$sql = 'select * from category where id = ?';
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(1, $id);
$q->execute();
while($rows = $q->fetch()){
    $cat[] = $rows['id'];
    $s = 'select * from category where category_id = ?';
    $q = $db->prepare($s);
    $q->bindParam(1, $rows['id']);
    $q->execute();
    while($row = $q->fetch()){
        $list[] = $row['id'];
    }

    $data  = array_push($cat, $list);

    echo $data;

}
```

I am getting 2 value when printing instead ids numbers

Comment: Can you put what you GET and what you EXPECT ?

Comment: It's better to paste the structure of the table here.

Comment: Don't use `array_push`, it's adding the values for some reason. What do you want one array with all the values? Sample: `$array1[] = 1;
$array2[] = 1;
echo array_push($array1, $array2);`

Comment: I am getting int 2 value, I am expecting categories and parent subcategories all into one array.

Comment: Table Structure: ID    NAME   CATEGORY_ID

Answer (score 0):

are you want to merge $cat and $list?

**you can try:**

```
array_merge($cat, $list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
$sql = 'select * from category where id = ?';
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(1, $id);
$q->execute();
$data = array();
while($rows = $q->fetch()){
    $cat[] = $rows['id'];
    $s = 'select * from category where category_id = ?';
    $q = $db->prepare($s);
    $q->bindParam(1, $rows['id']);
    $q->execute();
    while($row = $q->fetch()){
    $list[] = $row['id'];
    }

    $data = array_merge($data, $cat, $list);
    //$data = array_unique($data);

    print_r($data);

}
```

Notice the `$data = array();` before the while loop. With `array_merge` you merge categories and subcategories with the $data array into the data array.

If you happen to get duplicted value you do not need or want, simply uncomment `$data = array_unique($data);` and it will erase duplicated entries for you.

Please clarify your question, if I do not address your problem and I will update my answer.

Have fun, may the source be with you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried your solution error is Array to string conversion

Comment: because of the `echo $data` ($data is an array, echo is for echoing Strings), should be print_r($data) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of this post [combine-results-from-two-pdo-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529824/combine-results-from-two-pdo-queries)

```
$id = '1';
$results = array();
$sql = 'select * from category where id = ?';
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindParam(1, $id);
    $q->execute();
    while($rows = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[] = $rows['id'];
    } 
    $s = 'select * from category where category_id = ?';
    $q = $db->prepare($s);
    $q->bindParam(1, $id);
    $q->execute();
    while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $row['id'];
    }

    var_dump($results);
```